# Run python script through swift

Tags: python, swift, macos, foundation

I'm quite new to swift but I'm trying to run a python script through swift code. This is my code so far however the output I keep getting is zsh: permission denied. I'm not sure how to proceed. Is there any for me to be able to run the python script.

My current method

```
class func runCode(launchPath: String, cmd: [String]) -> String {
        let pipe = Pipe()
        let process = Process()
        process.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        process.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", cmd)]
        process.standardOutput = pipe
        let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        process.launch()
        
        return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8) ?? "Error"
    }
```

Method Call

```
print(Shortcuts.runCode(launchPath: "/usr/bin/python", cmd: [contentView.controller.path]))
```

Output
zsh:2: permission denied:

Comment: have you checked permissions on `/usr/bin/python` and the target script for the executing user?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do check permissions, the target script is correct though. How could I check permssion?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the process that you are running ends up being `/bin/zsh -c [contentView.controller.path]` — i.e., you aren't actually running Python at all. Note that you don't actually use the `launchPath` argument in the `runCode` method.

It seems to me like you should be doing this instead:

```swift
let pipe = Pipe()
let process = Process()
process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/python"
process.arguments = [String(format:"%@", contentView.controller.path)]
process.standardOutput = pipe
let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
process.launch()

return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8) ?? "Error"
```

I didn't put it in a function because I'm not sure what else you use the `runCode` function for, but this should work for your specific example.