# How to use zsh with profiles in swift and get output?

Tags: swift, macos, homebrew, zsh

I'm trying to work with `zsh` in Swift, and homebrew. I run into this issue every time I run my code. It can't find the command `brew`. I'm trying to run the `brew list` command through Sswift and get the output or listed packages, and then continue to display that. Is there a way to include the zsh profile with brew in the Swift command, but still produce output?

```
func run(_ cmd: String) -> String? {
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/local/Home"
    process.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", cmd)]
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.launch()
    return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
}

func test(){
    do {
        run("brew list")
    } catch {
        print("errpr")
    }
}
```

Comment: "everytime I run my code" What code?

Comment: func run(_ cmd: String) -> String? {
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/local/Home"
    process.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", cmd)]
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.launch()
    return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
}
func test(){
    do {
        run("brew list")
    } catch {
     print("errpr")
    }
}

Comment: Edit your question to add your code. Code in comments is not readable.

Comment: What is your launch path `"/usr/local/Home"`? What's that?

Comment: So basically this is an xy question. This has nothing to do with "the zsh profile". You have not at all understood how to use Process.

Comment: Where did you guys copy this from? There's some guide/article there that's out of date that's sending noobs astray https://stackoverflow.com/q/63210973/3141234 We should get the authors to update/fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of issues here. I'll tackle them one by one:

> ```swift
> process.launchPath = "/usr/local/Home"
> ```

The launch path is the actual executable you want this `Process` to launch. Unless `/usr/local/Home` is some binary or script we don't know about, that's probably not what you want.

Furthermore, there's no involvement of `zsh`, anywhere in the code you showed.

> ```swift
> String(format:"%@", cmd)
> ```

This does precisely nothing. You're creating a new string from a format string that only includes the value of `cmd`, which is ... already a String. In Objective C this would have had the effect of copying `cmd`, but given that `String` is a value type in Swift, this copying has no effect.

> ```swift
> run("brew list")
> ```

This is a misunderstanding of how program arguments work. At the OS level, program arguments are an array of strings. Not just one large array.

When you do something like `brew list` in a shell (like `zsh`), it's the shell's job to parse apart this string by spaces, and come up with an array of strings of individual arguments to pass to the OS (via `execv` and friends).
There's a few ways to invoke `brew`. The more "roundabout"

```
import Foundation

func run(_ cmd: String) -> String? {
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    process.arguments = [
        "-l", // Login shell
        "-c", // Evaluate input from argument
        cmd // The commands to evaluate
    ]
    
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    
    process.launch()
    return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
}

let output = run("brew list")
print(output ?? "<nil>")
```

Though even with `-l`, I can't get this to read my path configuration that I set in `~/.zshrc`. I'm not sure why this is.

Instead, you can just use a more direct way and just invoke `brew` directly, with no shell middleman.

```swift
import Foundation

func runBrewCommand(_ args: [String]) -> String? {
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/opt/homebrew/bin/brew"
    process.arguments = args
    
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    
    process.launch()
    return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
}

let output = runBrewCommand(["list"])
print(output ?? "<nil>")
```

Comment: I end up with an error, path not accessible for the first one, and brew not found for the second one.

Comment: Well, where is your `brew` binary installed? Mine is in the default location, `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`

Comment: mine is there too. Do I need to add special permissions to the app?

Comment: @Zac Well, your app can't be sand-boxed if you want to use `Process` with files outside your app's sandbox.

Comment: @Zac Which article did you copy the original snippet from?